# How can I develop a custom "non-fullscreen" softkeyboard for tablets?

Tags: keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android

I have the sample of softkeyboard. When I install it on a android 2.x, it has the following non-fullscreen view:

[image]

But when I install it on tablet 10in it gets whole of the screen like this:

[image]

How can I change the sample to have a non-fullscreen custom keyboard on tablet pcs like this image (default keyboard of tablet)?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code in InputMethodService solved my problem:

```
@Override
public boolean onEvaluateFullscreenMode() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, nice finding. The documentation is here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#FullscreenMode which says "The default implementation selects fullscreen mode when the screen is in a landscape orientation.."

Answer (score 1):

overide the following two methods from InputmethodService as bellow, this works always

```
@Override
    public void onUpdateExtractingVisibility(EditorInfo ei) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setExtractViewShown(false);
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onEvaluateFullscreenMode() {

        return false;
    }
```

This worked for me :) and if you want to show keyboard in fullscreen mode always then change both false to true.