# how can i make my custom keyboard to show in fullscreen mode always?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I tried this [How can I develop a custom "non-fullscreen" softkeyboard for tablets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048064/how-can-i-develop-a-custom-non-fullscreen-softkeyboard-for-tablets) to make it full screen mode but still its not full screen :(

And also i have tried the following in my code

```
 @Override
    public boolean onEvaluateFullscreenMode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFullscreenMode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setExtractViewShown(boolean shown) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.setExtractViewShown(true);
    }
```

Not working as expeced, can any one help me to solve this ?

Comment: have you tried this: http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/. It has lots of option which you need. have a look at its code.

Comment: does that support full screen mode always ?

Comment: It has a setting using which you can use for having full-screen mode. Its free app on play store, download it and have a go.. you will find a lots of helpful settings which you add in your own keyboard.

Comment: read my first comment.  http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/

Comment: Dude.. look around. There is a source link. People are to help you not spoon feed you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

overide the following two methods from InputmethodService as bellow

```
  @Override
    public void onUpdateExtractingVisibility(EditorInfo ei) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setExtractViewShown(true);
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onEvaluateFullscreenMode() {

        return true;
    }
```

This worked for me :)